# How to solve broadcasting error during summation of numpy arrays containing a (0, 6) array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As I am attempting to use one presented python script, its core part contains the NumPy array summation of a (0,6) array, while I'm coming across a broadcasting error. The basic broadcasting rules of numerical operations on NumPy arrays tell me `ValueError` will generate when I want to sum a (1000,6) array and a (0,6) array.

```
print a.shape
#(1000,6)
print b.shape
#(0,6)
a += b + 0.5
```

As might have been expected, "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,6)(0,6)(1000,6)" reported

I was wondering if there is anyway to fix this? Changing the shape of (0,6) array, or adding an extra dimension?

Comment: What does `print(b.shape)` give you? An array of only 1 dimension should have a shape of `(6,)`, not `(0,6)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In my case, both `print b.shape` or `print(b.shape)` in python2.7.9 and `print(b.shape)` in python.3.7.3 give the same output: (0,6)

Comment: That means that it contains no rows, `b` is an empty array, isn't it so?

Comment: What, pray tell, do you expect the result of broadcasting an empty array to be?

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I type the `print b`, I get the empty array: []. The b is generated from the (20,6) array c through the NumPy slicing: b = c.[start:end,:]. Suppose that "start" = 1, and "end" = 2, then b is not empty, but if "start" and "end" are larger than "20", it will generate an empty array. That's what confused me. According to the usage of this python script, "start" and "end" are always larger than 20. I'm not sure whether my usage about is correct or not. Or some changes should be made for numerical operation between (0,6) (it's empty) and (1000,6) arrays.

Comment: `numpy` (and Python lists) lets slice off the end.  So it's up to the user to determine whether the slice range produces the desired shape.  In this usage `b` has to be (1000,6) or (1,6).  Selecting `b = c[[start],:]` is an alternative that should work when `start` is in the right range, and throw an error when it is too large.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I have realized that it was the small sample size that caused my problem. For simplicity, I only employed 20 samples for test. So there are only 20 rows in array c, 'start' and 'end' are always selected within a large interval (>1000), after b = c.[start:end,:], there will be no row in array b (to be an empty array). When the sample size increases (>2000), c has more rows larger than 2000, if so, b will be a (1000,6) array eventually when difference between 'start' and 'end' is '1000'. Numerical operations can be carried out without no error reported.

Comment: Many thanks to yatu, Veedrac and hpaulj for all the assistance!